# Window location one level up

Tags: javascript, url, relative-path

This is my scenario:

I have my web page in folder:

http://www.example.com/example/index.html

I have media files in folder (one level up):

http://www.example.com/media/

and this files are linked in index.html like so: '../song1.mp3'

So when I read window.location.href from my web page I get this:

http://www.example.com/example/

But my media files are in location http://www.example.com/media/

Now I want to construct a download path for this media, but if I join window.location.href and media url I get this:

http://www.example.com/example/../song1.mp3

and I need to get this:

http://www.example.com/media/song1.mp3

what is the easiest way to manage this?

I am using javascript.

Comment: is it a possibility to just remove the `../` part in the mp3's name?

Comment: Why can't you link them in `index.html` using `/media/song1.mp3` instead?

Comment: andy - but I would still have to change this path: http://www.mydomain.com/example/ to this path: http://www.mydomain.com/media/. Vivin Paliath - this wont work since my media is one level up from index.html

Comment: this might sound a bit lazy, but its easier: then why don't you put the file beside the index.html, so you don't have the problem of building a path?

Comment: @Toniq It doesn't matter. If you present the link as `/media/song1.mp3` it will always be from the origin and it will work.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, but as you can see in what is already tried, the script is in `/example/`. so something like `../` is necessary.

Comment: @andy I was talking about the value in `href` for the anchor tag, which is what I'm assuming he's talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var filename = "../song1.mp3",

    domain   = "http://example.com/", // may be static or made by some black magic

    url      = domain + "media/" + filename.split("/").pop();
```

So you just split your path with the `../`-part, get the last element (would be `"song1.mp3"`) and put it together to `http://example.com/media/song1.mp3`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kfFsx/1/) your have a live example.